# JQuery append with forloop

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function that will append a **select-box** with possibility to choose **birthdate**. What is the best way to achieve that?

When i run that script the append inside the for-loop is added after the closing-select. Is there any logic to the append, or is it not strict? I thought that the forloop had to be finished before it continued.

```
function addChildOption(){
  if (counterOption < 3) {
    $("#add-child").append("<select name=\"child" + counterOption + "\" form=\"register\">");
    for(var i = year-15; i > 1900  ; i--){
          $("#add-child").append("<option class=\"choose-year\" value=" + i + ">" + i + "</option>");
    }
    $("#add-child").append("</select>");     
  }
}
```

***The result:***

```
<select form="register" name="child1"></select>
<option class="choose-year" value="1999">1999</option>
<option class="choose-year" value="1998">1998</option>
<option class="choose-year" value="1997">1997</option>
etc....
```

Comment: Mybe you should do `$('#add-child select").append(...`

Comment: You can only append elements, not tags. When you append the `select` element it has to be complete, you can't add the start tag and then the end tag. When you try to add the start tag, the browser will make a complete element out of it, so when you add the options they will end up after the select.

Answer (score 1):

You could construct the `select`, add the options to that variable, and then append it to the actual form:

```
var sel = $('<select name="child' + counterOption + '" form="register" />');

for(var i = year-15; i > 1900; i--) {
    sel.append($('<option value="' + i + '" class="choose-year">' + i+ '</option>'));
}

$('#add-child').append(sel);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addChildOption(){
  if (counterOption < 3) {
    var html = "<select name=\"child" + counterOption + "\" form=\"register\">");
    for(var i = year-15; i > 1900  ; i--){
          html += "<option class=\"choose-year\" value=" + i + ">" + i + "</option>");
    }
    html += "</select>"
    $("#add-child").append(html);     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For my part, I prefer to do thing like this :

```
function addChildOption() {
    if (counterOption < 3) {
        var addChild = $("#add-child");
        var mySelect = $("<select />").prop("name", "child" + counterOption).prop("form", "register").appendTo(addChild);
        for (var i = year - 15; i > 1900; i--) {
            $("<option />").addClass("choose-year").prop("value", i).text(i).appendTo(mySelect);
        }
    }
}
```

Like that, I directly add the select to the container, and then, the options to the select.

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery Queue](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.queue/)

```
function addChildOption(){
   if (counterOption < 3)
   {
      $("#add-child").append("<select name=\"child" + counterOption + "\" form=\"register\"></select>").queue(function(next){
         for(var i = year-15; i > 1900  ; i--) {
           $(this).children().append("<option class=\"choose-year\" value=" + i + ">" + i + " </option>");
         }
      next();
     });
   }
}
```